# Neural network to predict air flow from coordinate and fan speed

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to get a neural network to predict air velocity in a container. The input to the neural network is a coordinate (x, y) and the fan speed (in percentage) and from which is should approximate the velocities (u, v) at that point.
The grid looks like [this (ignore the red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4qpQ.png), where each green point is a coordinate. There are 10007 points.

I have used COMSOL to simulate the model with various fan speed scenarios (60%, 70%, 80%, 90%, 100%) and saved the data points for the above grid.

For each scenarios, I have 10007 coordinates (x, y), fan speed and 10007 data points (u, v).

For a fan speed of 100%, the u and v velocities looks [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhAhv.png), here x and y labels are the positions.

Here i would like to point out that most of the velocities are close to 0 and only a small portion of it have higher velocities.

To sum it up:

- 3 inputs: x, y and fan speed
- x and y identical for all scenarios (same points), only difference is the fan speed
- 10007*5 data points (5 scenarios)
- 2 outputs: u and v

I have tried with a fully connected neural network with 5 hidden layers with 40 neurons each, with a mse loss function, Adam optimizer. For this particular case i have tried with batch sizes of 10007, thus 1 iteration is a scenario but also tried with 10 and got roughly the same [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsVka.png)

It seems like its trying to minimize the loss by making the prediction became equal to the majority of the data, which is very small and then neglect the higher velocities, if that makes sense.

So, the questions:

- How to make the neural network put higher focus on the coordinates with higher velocities?
- What would be the best NN architecture for this kind of operation?
- What would your guess be on the depth and width of the neural network?
- Should I do any kind of scaling/standardization? If so, which?

Any input would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, BatchNormalization, InputLayer, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_normal
from tensorflow.math import square, sqrt

N = 40
layers = [N,N,N,N,N]

def NN(layers):              
    X = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1), name = "X")
    Y = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1), name = "Y")
    XY = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(name = "XY_Merging")([X, Y])
    Inflow = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1), name = "Inflow")
    concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(name = "Merging")([XY, Inflow])
    x = concat
    for i in layers:
        x = Dense(units=i, activation="tanh")(x)
    Output = Dense(units=2, kernel_initializer="glorot_normal", name = "Output")(x)
    model = Model(inputs=[X, Y, Inflow], outputs=Output)
    return model

model = NN(layers)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0000001), loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
model.summary()

model.fit({"X":y_train, "Y":x_train, "Inflow":Inflow_train}, Y_train, batch_size=10007, epochs=1000, verbose=1, shuffle = False)
```

[Model Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJDFT.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

On thing that might help in general is to set up your CFD model grid so that you have a much higher grid density in the areas where you have meaningful results, and a sparser grid where you expect the results to be close to zero. Having most of your data (all those 0s) provide no useful information to the ML model will make it hard to get good results.

This might also be something where a simpler regression model might be better than a neural network. Have you tried that?